# Calculating FID scores for GAN models between two different image directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am calculating FID (Frechet Inception Distance) score of my CycleGAN model using [this reference](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-the-frechet-inception-distance-fid-from-scratch/). I have input photos in a directory and generated 'artistic' photos in another directory.

```
input_photo_path = 'data/'
art_photo_path = 'images/'

import PIL
import numpy as np
import glob

def convert_image_to_numpy(image_path_dir):
    arr = []
    for img in glob.iglob(image_path_dir + '*.jpg', recursive=True):
        image = PIL.Image.open(img)
        image_array = np.array(image)
        arr.append(image_array)
    return np.array(arr) 



img1 = convert_image_to_numpy(cat_photo_path)
img2 = convert_image_to_numpy(art_photo_path)

img1 = preprocess_and_scale(img1)
img2 = preprocess_and_scale(img2)

fid = calculate_fid(inception_model, img1, img2)
```

This looks all good logically. But the problem is - the input images and the generated images are not necessarily in the same order. Say my `input_photo_path` has images in the order `[001_r.jpg, 002_r.jpg, 003_r.jpg, ..., 012_r.jpg]` but my `art_photo_path` has images in the order `[1.jpg, 10.jpg, 2.jpg ...]`. And `10.jpg` in the `art_photo_path` is NOT the generated version of `002_r.jpg` in the `input_photo_path`.

I think that definitely messes up the FID calculation. Any suggestion on how should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FID computation doesn't depend on the ordering of images. It takes the statistics of the entire dataset (i.e it calculates the mean and covariance across the feature dimension for all the examples present in the dataset). So, the ordering doesn't matter.

Here's the pytorch implementation: https://github.com/mseitzer/pytorch-fid/blob/master/src/pytorch_fid/fid_score.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).